# IoT Edge with certificate DPS provisioning fails on cert permissions error

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have set up Azure IoT Edge on Ubuntu 20.04 and configured it to provision via DPS with self-signed certificates. If I store the id cert and key in /home/[user]/certs it works fine. If I move the cert files to /var/certs and update /etc/aziot/config.toml accordingly, I get the following errors from `sudo iotedge system logs`:

```
systemd[1]: Started Azure IoT Identity Service.
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [INFO] - Starting service...
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [INFO] - Version - 1.2.4
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [INFO] - Provisioning starting. Reason: Startup
aziot-certd[2113]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [INFO] - <-- GET /certificates/device-id?api-version=2020-09-01 {"host": "certd.sock"}
aziot-certd[2113]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - !!! internal error
aziot-certd[2113]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - !!! caused by: could not read cert file
aziot-certd[2113]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - !!! caused by: Permission denied (os error 13)
aziot-certd[2113]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [INFO] - --> 500 {"content-type": "application/json"}
aziot-keyd[2121]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [INFO] - <-- POST /keypair?api-version=2020-09-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "56"}
aziot-keyd[2121]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - Permission denied (os error 13)
aziot-keyd[2121]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - !!! internal error
aziot-keyd[2121]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - !!! caused by: could not create key pair
aziot-keyd[2121]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - !!! caused by: could not create key pair: AZIOT_KEYS_RC_ERR_EXTERNAL
aziot-keyd[2121]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [INFO] - --> 500 {"content-type": "application/json"}
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - Failed to provision with IoT Hub, and no valid device backup was found: internal error
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - service encountered an error
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - caused by: internal error
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - caused by: could not create certificate
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] - caused by: internal error
aziot-identityd[5699]: 2021-12-20T03:46:33Z [ERR!] -    0: <unknown>
aziot-identityd[5699]:    1: <unknown>
systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

There is obviously a permissions error with the new certificate location, but I can't find proper documentation on what users/groups/services need which permissions. Some docs say the user iotedge needs read access, but even making iotedge the owner does not fix the problem. There also appear to be groups aziotid, aziotks, aziotcs which may or may not need access, but assigning ownership or read permissions to those groups doesn't fix the problem. If anyone can help with their experience or point me to valid up-to-date docs I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Checkout this doc: [Configure IoT Edge with the new certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-manage-device-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=linux#configure-iot-edge-with-the-new-certificates) "Make sure that the service has read permissions for the directories holding the certificates and keys"

Comment: Thanks @asergaz, the read permissions and ownership didn't fix the problem. The only way I could get it to work was to:
- copy the identity cert to /var/lib/aziot/certd/certs and make aziotcs the file owner
- copy the private key to /var/lib/aziot/keyd/keys and make aziotks the file owner

Comment: Is this issue related and helps clarify? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/85616